# Firing global event Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to create an error handling dialog for my interface. The dialog will simply display the error message from the iron ajax. I am able to access this message and would like an event to fire when the ajax comes back with an error. This is the code for firing the event:

```
  testError(e) {
    const err = e.detail.request.xhr.response.message;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('error'));
  }
```

This is the code for adding the event listener:

```
  class ErrorHandling extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'error-handling'; }
    static get properties() {
      return {
      }
    }
    constructor() {
      super();
      this._boundListener = this.error.bind(this);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback();
      window.addEventListener('error', this._boundListener);
      console.log("connectedCallback ran");
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
      super.disconnectedCallback();
      window.removeEventListener('error', this._boundListener);
      console.log("disconnectedCallback ran");
    }
    _boundListener(e) {
      console.log("boundlistener ran");
    }
```

I have read through the documentation to try and work out why this isn't working but have had no success. Any reason why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). With this you can add the options bubbles: true which will make the event bubble up until it reached the window.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('error', {bubbles: true}));
```

To recive this event you have to [register](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('error', this.myEventListener)
```

Comment: thanks for this - I have added it however I am getting an error in the listener html that says "cannot read property bind of undefined relating to the line:

this._boundListener = this.error.bind(this);

Any ideas?

Comment: Well honestly i was wondering too what this means i guess you want to bind to the error event with this?

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events

I got it from the polymer documentation in the section "listener on outside elements"

Comment: My bad i was reading the wrong line sry your code must be this.error = this._boundListener.bind(this); this.addEventListener('error', this.error)

Comment: this is now my listener html   class ErrorHandling extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'error-handling'; }
    static get properties() {
      return {
      }
    }
    ready() {
      super.ready;
      this.error = this._boundListener.bind(this);
      this.addEventListener('error', this.error);
    }
    test(e) {
      console.log("test ran");
    }

It still throws an error on .bind(this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173475/discussion-between-devads-and-pascal-l).

Comment: I have added a new question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964615/iron-ajax-not-firing-event-on-error